# Modify an AJAX html response with each function

Tags: jquery, each

Could someone tell me why this code does not **update** the data response? It's a simple example of the *each* function.

Here is the ajax requested html file:

```
<html>
<div class="new">
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Heading1</h2>
        <p>Text1</p>
        <p><a href="#">Link1</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Heading2</h2>
        <p>Text2</p>
        <p><a href="#">Link2</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

and here is the main file body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<textarea id="gethtml" rows="40" cols="125"></textarea>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";
    $(function() {

        $.get('file.html', function(data) {
            ajaxfunction(data);
        });

        function ajaxfunction(data) {
            $(data).find(".span4").each(function () {
                $(this).find("p").eq(0).text("Hello");
                $(this).find("p").eq(0).after("<p>newline</p>");
                console.log($(this));
            });
            $("#gethtml").val(data);
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the console displays the correct data for each span4, but why doesnt the "data" string gets updated to reflect the changes?

**EDIT**

```
function ajaxfunction(data) {
            var tree = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
            $(tree).find(".span4").each(function () {
                $(this).find("p").eq(0).text("Hello");
                $(this).find("p").eq(0).after("<p>newline</p>");
                console.log($(this));
            });
            $("#gethtml").val(tree.html());
}
```

This places in the textarea, ie `<p>Hello</p><p>newline</p>`.
So, in order to also put a new line into it, then I'll have to modify it as a string, right?

Thanks!

Comment: `tree` is already a jQuery object.  Don't call `$()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a string.

Your `each` code parses this string into a DOM tree and modifies it.
However, you don't do anything with this DOM tree.

Your `val()` call uses the original string again.

Instead, you need to call `html()` to get the source of the modified DOM tree.

For more information, see [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html).